# Is Java Modelling Language executable?

Tags: java, jml

I am studying software engineering course, and there i saw the usage of JML. Here is an example piece of code:

```
//@ requires f >= 0.0 
public float sqrt(float f) { 
   return f/2;
}
```

It says that formal JML specifications are executable!

My question is, when we call this sqrt function with f=-4,does this code give an error or throw an exception or give any warnings? I tried it on my computer it just worked well and printed out -2. Then what does it mean that JML are executable? Why don't we use just comments to do this? Can anyone explain?

Thanks

Comment: Well, here is the code and i am asking something about the code. I do not understand the downvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JML is not part of Java. It is an extension designed by a coalition of researchers but without official endorsement. As such, JML annotations are not taken into account by the Java compiler, but you can compile a JML-annotated Java program with a special compiler so that the executable specifications will be taken into account. For instance, [JML4C](http://www.cs.utep.edu/cheon/download/jml4c/doc.php).

Answer (score 2):

Well, this code itself does not create any warning for you. There exist a variety of tools which make use of JML specs, for example:

- jmlrac: test for violations of assertions during execution
- ESC/Java2: static verification; compile-time proving that contracts are never violated
- jmldoc: javadoc-style documentation
- jmlc: assertion-checking compiler
- jmlunit: unit testing tool

In addition to that, JML specs, if properly used, reveal programmer intentions to foreign readers/maintainers of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing the square root (`Math.sqrt(f)`, see `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt(double)`) but dividing by 2 (`f/2`). So there is nothing wrong with that. What you need is using Math.sqrt(...) if this is what I assume you need looking at the name of your method.

Comment: well actually it is not important here. I just wonder this: I gave a precondition to the function saying that the parameteter must be >=0 but i call it with parameter<0 and it works. If JML is executable, why is this the case? Why is there no errors or warnings?

Comment: Oh, then in this case I think you are missing the last `;` at the end of the line.